# execute sqldatasource with button

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I have two queries that I want to be able to run on a page.  I have a button, gridview and sqldatasource at the top of the page and another button, gridview and sqldatasource with the second query at the bottom.

How do I associate the buttons with their particular grid and datasource.

right now when I click either button, both gridview1 and gridview2 populate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming in the markup for your grdiviews you have set the datasource property to one of the sql data sources.

I'm also going on the assumption that you do not want any data in the gridviews when the page first loads.

If that is the case you can simply leave the datasource property of the gridviews blank.  Then in the click event handler for the buttons you can populate the grid view you want.

Here is the c# code I used to do this

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        //If you only want to show one grid at a time
        GridView2.DataSource = null;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView2.DataSource = SqlDataSource2;
        GridView2.DataBind();
        //If you only want to show one grid at a time
        GridView1.DataSource = null;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```