# Gridview is not getting connected (not showing data) to SQLDataSource on ButtonClick

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource, buttonclick

aspx.cs code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
}
```

Aspx code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click1" 
        Text="Button" />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName 
%>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Machine]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Initially DataSourceID of Grid view is not assigned to SQLDataSource.
I want Table to be displayed on button click only on same page.

Reference - [execute sqldatasource with button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189879/execute-sqldatasource-with-button)

Comment: Did you even Google GridView? 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In case we set DataSourceID in properties to SQLDataSource, the data is getting displayed, by default. I want to show data on button click.

Comment: You do know that a GridView is a html table with columns. And of course you know that columns have to be added in order to show data, either manually or ...